# python: can't open file 'scripts/mk_make.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: bash, scripts, python

I am trying to run Oyente tool using the commands mentioned in [How to use Oyente, a smart contract security analyzer — Solidity Tutorial](https://medium.com/haloblock/how-to-use-oyente-a-smart-contract-security-analyzer-solidity-tutorial-86671be93c4b).

I am executing the following command on Ubuntu 18.04 and get the error shown:

```
(envsp) ~$ python scripts/mk_make.py — python 
python: can't open file 'scripts/mk_make.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Python version is:

```
(envsp) ~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
(envsp) :~$
```

Comment: And where is the scripts folder, are you running the python command from that folder's parent folder?

Comment: And I see your doing `python3 --version` but trying to run `python scripts/mk_make.py` these versions of python aren't the same!

Comment: I have not created any scripts folder. The link which I am following does not ask me to create any folder.

Comment: I am getting the same error with python3:    python3 scripts/mk_make.py — python3
:python3: can't open file 'scripts/mk_make.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: it doesn't exist but let me try to run those steps

Comment: I think you should drop a comment for the author of that post as I see some typos that don't make it clear how the steps are to be followed

Comment: You can try to find the file with this command: `find / -name mk_name.py 2>/dev/null`